# inserting kernel module in Linux-3.14

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am inserting kernel module insmod hello.ko, it gives:

```
insmod: can't insert 'hello.ko': kernel does not support requested operation.
```

I am using same `uImage` on target.

Module compilation was successful. Before make I have set

```
export ARCH=arm
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-.,
export PATH=$PATH:/home/bsp/rskrza1_bsp-master/output/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2014.02_linux/bin/
```

Makefile is

```
obj-m := hello.o

KERNELDIR ?= /home/bsp/rskrza1_bsp-master/output/linux-3.14/
PWD := $(shell pwd)

all:
$(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions
```

Please let me know how can I solve it.

Thanks, Awadhesh

Comment: Where is the kernel running (which hardware)?

Comment: Try to see if you can have any more specific message using `dmesg`

Comment: Is "CONFIG_MODULES=y" in your .config file ?

Comment: @Mikes posted an answer that should have been a comment. SInce it will probably be deleted, I'll copy it here: "Why do you cross-compile? On which machine do you try to insmod? What does `cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip | grep -w CONFIG_MODULES`, on the insmod'ding machine, tell?"

Comment: Keith, I suppose `zgrep CONFIG_MODULES /proc/config*` will work faster :-) On the other hand the `/proc/config` might be absent.